# How to Change Background Color of Part of the navbar Using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3.2.0.

**I want to make this navbar background part red (I mean only this). Marked as number "3"**

Here I made how it should look like in reality (see section marked 3 of problem):

http://postimg.org/image/g0fph7o75/

Here you can find the HTML/CSS code I'm working on:

http://jsfiddle.net/b8yczde2/

(snipped from jsfiddle)
```

```
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#portfolio"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span><br/> Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#skills"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal"></span><br/> Skills</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#blog"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span><br/> Blog</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li style="border-left: 1px solid rgb(215,215,215);"><a href="#contact"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span><br/> Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li style="padding-right: 0.8em;"><a href="#about"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><br/> CV</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<section class="section-bg intro-bg">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">Mooses are cool and big and stuff.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

```

Comment: Trying to clarify -- are you trying to fix the parts that are still white in your navbar? Sometimes the easiest way to pinpoint what you're trying to change is to use the "inspect element" feature of the Chrome browser. You right click the area you're trying to fix and view exactly what parts of the code the browser is using to render the element. You've got a lot of stying gong on there - it might help. :)  Good luck and ping me if you're still completely stuck!

Comment: If you only want to change the color on a few specific divs, make a new class `.red-bg{ color: #DE0B24; }` (color code from your picture). Bootstrap has the class called `danger`, but it probably won't work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a css rule:

```
.navbar {
   background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b8yczde2/8/